# How to integrate AXIOS on ReactJS base CDN

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Now i'm doing build a front page use ReactJS but base CDN format not base node/npm. now i want to integrate AXIOS on it but face an issue about that. All the code that i implement error.. i will share my code

this is my index.html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Buynow Project</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" > 
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script> 
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="root"></div>  

    <script type="text/babel" src="catalog/view/theme/default/template/account/purpletree_multivendor/buynow/App.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel">
        ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
    </script> 
    
  </body>
</html>
```

this is my app.js code

```
function Product() { 

  axios.post('http://<domainName>.com/api/product_ec7cac9007758d89656160f668_1381')
  .then(function (response) {
    // handle success
    console.log("result response");
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log("result error");

    console.log(error);
  })
  .then(function () {
    console.log("last");

    // always executed
  }); 

  return ( 
    <div>
        DISPLAY PRODUCT DETAIL 
        {/* will display detail product value */}
    </div>
    
    )
  
}  
 
class App extends React.Component { 
  render() {
    return( 
        <div>
            <Product />
        </div> 
    )
  }
}
```

from this code. there are no result for the response. evendo the `console.log` for

```
console.log("result response");
console.log("result error"); 
console.log("last");
```

not display also. so i don't know what is response when run this code.

actually i also tried another code for fetch data. i will share the code

second code

```
const uf = await axios.post("http://<domainName>.com/api/product_ec7cac9007758d89656160f668_1381");
const response = await fetch(uf);
const data = await response.jso(response);

console.log("second code"); 
console.log(data);
```

third code

```
  const fetchOptions = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Accept: "application/json",
        } 
    };

    const response = await fetch('http://<domainName>.com/api/product_ec7cac9007758d89656160f668_1381', fetchOptions);
  console.log(response);
```

and both have same error result

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: http://localhost:81/website/App.js: await is a reserved word (36:13) (at babel.min.js:7:10099)
 34 | 
 35 | function Product() {
> 36 |   const uf = await axios.get("http://<domainName>.com/api/product_ec7cac9007758d89656160f668_1381");
    |               ^
 37 |   const response = await fetch(uf);
 38 |   const data = await response.jso(response);
 39 |
```

please help. i not sure how to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use await, when `async` function is there.

```
async function Product() {
 const uf = await axios.get("http://<domainName>.com/api/product_ec7cac9007758d89656160f668_1381");
           
const response = await fetch(uf);
const data = await response.jso(response);
```

Learn more here -
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_async.asp